# How to specify a file name for an Android or iOS build in App Center

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

We're having an Android and an iOS build configured in App Center. It is set up as in the following screenshot.

[image: build]

In the configuration dropdown list we can choose to build a test or production version. When the build is done we can't identify by the file name if the build is a test or production build. In the distribution list we just see a list of versions, but we would like to have it post-fixed with Test or Production.

I am wondering how we can specify a variable file name that contains the value specified in the Configuration dropdown list. Who can point me in the right direction?